# Javascript News Ticker

Tags: javascript, jquery, ticker

I'm using this code to fade in and out different messages.
It works ok. The only problem is that it delays the first loop. And I have to wait before the first message shows up. I tried to fix it but with no luck!

```
var loops = 0;
function t() {
    var news = new Array("Text01", "Text02");

    var l = news.length; 
    var fade = 300; 
    var delay = 6000; 
    var process = delay+fade+fade; 
    var n = 0; 
    var f = ''; 


    for(i=0; i<l; i++){
        f += "<span class='ticker' id='str"+i+"'>"+news[i]+"</span> ";
        $("#newsticker").html(f);
    }

    for(i=0; i<l; i++){
        n++; 
        var offset = i*process; 
        $("#str"+i).delay(offset).fadeIn(fade).delay(delay).fadeOut(fade); 
    }

    var loop_process = n*process;

    if(loops==0){ 
        setTimeout("t()", 0); 
    }

    setTimeout("t()", loop_process); 
    loops++; 
}

t();
```

HTML

```
<span id="newsticker"></span>
```

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is here? Can you try to explain it better or maybe make a JSFiddle where we can see the problem?

Comment: Hey, your method was confusing me but I created a new script based around it on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W84uP/1/) - how does that work for you? (change sameTime var to switch between simultaneous fading or not)

Comment: I copied your code into a fiddle and found different problems.  The ticker elements were all initially visible.  I changed the html to initially set `display:none`.  (Also `setTimeout` should be passed a function, and there was no need to set `html` repeatedly while building the items). http://jsfiddle.net/k59qq/2/

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot for your help. I tried to implement all the methods described above but I still have the same problem. :( It's strange... If I refresh the page the first loop appears correctly but if I type the address the first loop is delayed. This is where I use it http://projectspace70.com. Now there is the same text showing over and over again but I'll translate it in different languages.